# htaccess - redirect to subfolder but keep access to up level folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Here is my project folder structure in my server:

```
-- mainfolder
   -- folder1
      -- file1.js
      -- file2.js
   -- folder2
      -- file3
      -- file4
      -- subfolder1
      -- subfolder2
      -- index.html
```

I need to setup `.htaccess` file in order to have `www.example.com` always redirecting to `www.example.com/folder2` where I have the `index.html` file. Now that `index.html` in **`folder2`** refers to files in **`folder1`**:

**index.html**

```
...
<script src="../folder1/file1.js" > </script>
<script src="../folder1/file2.js" > </script>
...
```

I have tried this `.htaccess` config to always redirect to `/mainfolder/`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !mainfolder/
RewriteRule (.*) /mainfolder/$1 [L]
```

but this way I always should enter `www.example.com/mainfolder/folder2` to access my website.

So is there a way to always point to `folder2` and, most important, allow the files in `folder2` to access `folder1` files?

Also I have tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !mainfolder/folder2/
RewriteRule (.*) /mainfolder/folder2/$1 [L]
```

but the problem is that I get errors from `index.html` because it can't access files in `folder1` because browser thinks that Document Root is `/mainfolder/folder2/` and so it does not know `/mainfolder/folder1`.

In summary, I need to:

- access `/mainfolder/folder2/index.html` when entering `www.example.com`;
- allow the files in `folder2` to access `folder1` files.

P.s. I can't change `DocumentRoot` of my web server, I just can edit `.htaccess` file.

Thanks

Comment: is it possible to use `/folder1/file1.js` instead of `../folder1/file1.js`?

Comment: I could change it but there are other files in `folder2` that uses paths to `folder1` that I can't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one worked for me in all cases I tested. Hope it helps. If something is not right let me know.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder1/(.*)$ /mainfolder/folder1/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^$ /mainfolder/folder2/index.html [L]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mainfolder/folder2/$1 [L]
```